# AngularJS ng-class not applying bootstrap error classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm building a multi-step AngularJS form that adds bootstrap error classes on ng-class. I'm using this tutorial as my base for building the form http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-multi-step-form-using-ui-router#building-our-angular-app-app.js.

**Question:** Why are my ng-class css classes not being applied to my form-group wrapper when child fields are invalid? My submit button stays disabled until form fields are correct, but error classes and styling never gets applied.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error has-feedback' : longForm.fullName.$invalid && !longForm.fullName.$pristine}">
  <label class="hidden-xs" for="FullName">Full Name</label>
  <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" name="FullName" placeholder="Your Full Name" ng-model="longFormData.fullName" required />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-cta btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="longForm.$invalid">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case it's actually really simple.

You have the name of your input as `FullName`, but you are referencing it as `fullName`.

The property names published on the form controller are case sensitive, so just change the case of either:

`name="FullName"` to `name="fullName"`

OR

`longForm.fullName` to `longForm.FullName`

Comment: I'm also not sure if the class names in `ng-class` should be specified together like that

Comment: @JoseM - They actually can. It's just a JavaScript property name at the end of the day, and spaces in the middle of JavaScript properties is 100% legal :)

Comment: @JasonSpence - No problem man :) Admittedly the form stuff is really easy to get mixed up on due to all the repetition.